# Should PHP Notices be turned off in a Production environment?

Tags: php

I recently took over a very old PHP website that is generating a 1 GB php-errors.log file each week.  The majority of the Notices are from undefined variables and indexes.  In the long run, these notices should be fixed in the php code.

The customer is getting a random error on a few of their screens.  The errors so far cannot be duplicated.

The number of Notices in the log file are overwhelming and I wonder if I should turn them off in the php.ini.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, if it's causing you problems, then yes.

Comment: If you are _actively_ working on them, then disabling just notices (i.e. not warnings or above) in live seems like a good idea. But don't do that in order to avoid fixing them `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the code - notices are there for a reason. Just ensure that they just go to a log file and do not give the game away to the users of your web site

Answer (score 2):

Errors/notices should be hidden, but not turned off on production. They should be saved in logs and fixes as soon as you can.

But of course you can disable them, it's not good, but you can. If you do that, then in case of problem, you'll not be able to check what was wrong. It not helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should always attempt to code with as little errors as possible, but if there is an error you definitely don't want it to display to a user. So yes turn off in production environments, but use best practices in coding.